# Checking the application state with redux returns object

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

the code react.js below uses redux to save a state when I run the setState the state is saved correctly (I veficato with plugin chrome) but when I go to read the state getState it returns me [object] how do I solve this?

**React.js code:**

```
import {createStore} from "redux";

const initalCantiere={
    IdCantiere: 0
 };

const store=createStore(
    cantiereReducer,
);

export function cantiereReducer(state=initalCantiere,action){
    switch(action.type){
        case "getValue":
           return action.payload;
        default:
          return state;
    }
}

export function cantiereSet(IdCantiere){
    console.log("IdCantiere set: "+IdCantiere);
    store.dispatch({ type: "getValue", payload: IdCantiere });
}

export function getCantiere(){
    return store.getState();
}
```

Comment: why are you returning `return action.payload;` ?

Comment: @decpk what do you return?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think your getting whole state by

```
  return store.getState();
```

**getState()** method
Returns the current state tree of your application.( that means [object])

instead of this try

```
   return store.getState().IdCantiere;
```

Comment: it return undefined

Comment: sorry for mistake it is   return store.getState().IdCantiere;

Comment: with your solution i have 0 and not value use in cantiereSet

Comment: that because  i think your not set IdCantiere value to state ,  before  return in  "getValue" action , save IdCantiere to state  ( state. IdCantiere = action.payload ) you and you want to just return in reducer function